# How to load a dll under a bin folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to apply dll to my aspx (with code behind), I didn't create a project, just opening the aspx and cs file using visual studio 2012

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8422
Microsoft Developer Support OLE File Property Reader  (the dsofile.dll)

I'm trying to read the file properties by using this dll.

What is the easiest and fastest way to import this dll without using add reference in visual studio?

i put the dsofile.dll under the bin folder, and use "using DSOfile", but the dll not been found.

Comment: is there any reason not to use "Add Reference" in VS ?

Comment: You can just load it via Reflection

Comment: any demo code? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351/en-us):

> The Dsofile.dll sample file is an in-process ActiveX component for
>   programmers that use Microsoft Visual Basic .NET or the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework.

These articles will tell you what to do:

- [Calling COM Components from .NET Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx)
- [C# 4.0, the Dynamic Keyword and COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714583.aspx)